# Width matter in bootstrap class chrome browser compatibility

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is Google chrome browser shows the search box in a new line whereas the Mozilla firefox display correctly as inline.I want to solve the problem using bootstrap classes
Can anyone help me to solve this problem in the code

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse4">
        <form class="form-inline navbar-form navbar-right" action="http://example.com/search/search" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by author, title, ISBN here">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button></span>
                    </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you adding the search box to navbar but Don't do this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse4">
        <form class="form-inline navbar-form navbar-right" action="http://example.com/search/search" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by author, title, ISBN here">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button></span>
                    </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Do this instead:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <form class="form-inline navbar-form navbar-right" action="http://example.com/search/search" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by author, title, ISBN here">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button></span>
                    </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Tip: You can always use `Inspect element` in chrome to debug your code.